# The looping index returns 0 resolved during execution in a JMeter Loop Controller

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have a problem with the looping index for a looping controller.
I have a loop named exampleLoop and are accessing the looping index from inside the loop with a JSR223 sampler using groovy.

My code in the JSR223 Sampler:

```
log.info("Iteration nr: " + vars.get("__jm__exampleLoop__idx"))
```

When executing the loop 5 times I get:

Iteration nr: 0

Iteration nr: 0

Iteration nr: 0

Iteration nr: 0

Iteration nr: 0

It seems like the looping index is caching the first value(Starting value 0). Do anyone know how to get the looping index variable to be updated every iteration iteration so that I will get the following print out:

Iteration nr: 0

Iteration nr: 1

Iteration nr: 2

Iteration nr: 3

Iteration nr: 4

I have tried to enable and disable the "Cache compiled script if available" option but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The value will be incremented during each iteration caused by the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), iterations of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or other Logic Controllers will not be taken into consideration (or you will have to refer them using their own names, the [JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) with their respective values can be visualized using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination)

   [image]
2. Make sure that your Loop Controller is named as `exampleLoop`

Demo:

[image]

Comment: This answer is very good and shows in a clear way how Loop counters work.

In my case the issue was butterfingers. There was an earand space in the name of the Loop Controller.